# Phabricator: how to make arc diff ignore untracked files and how to edit reviewers

Tags: git, phabricator, arcanist

I recently set up Phabricator for my team, and I have two questions regarding to "arc" behavior.

1. When I want to send a review, I do
   git add 
   git commit
   arc diff 
   now, if I have untracked files, arc will not let me do it unless I commit those untracked files or delete them, is there a way to just let arc diff generate reviews  for what I have commited but have not pushed.
2. When I successfully proceed with 'arc diff', it ask me to fill up "test plan", which is fine, and "reviewers"... which is troublesome in my opinion, because of two reasons: (1), I don't know what format of the person is expected, and I don't know how to spell some of the names (2) When I need 10 people to review my code, I need to write ten names. Is there a way I can leave this blank first, and then go to phabricator.mydomain.com to edit the reviews, and send the review request?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For number 1: If you have changes in untracked files, they should be in the git ignore and arc will respect it.  Otherwise, it should give you an option to append them to the commit, you should be able to select no.

For number 2: it is expecting the username for the reviewers.  Also, you can put a project as the reviewer and it will message all members of the project.  Simply put `#Project_Name` as the reviewer.

Comment: Regarding #1: this simply doesn't work. I'm getting `Usage Exception: You can not continue with untracked changes. Add them, discard them, or mark them as ignored before proceeding.` What is going on here. It's very common to have many intermediate files floating around, and I should have to affect everyone else's .gitignore files because of this. There really must be a different way

Comment: `Unstaged changes` are not the same as `untracked files`.  `Unstaged changes` are changes to files that have been checked in to the repo but the change hasn't been committed.  `Untracked files`, however, are files that have never been checked in.  `Untracked files` will make the diff process inconvenient and, in some cases, fail.  `Unstaged changes` are an indication of work that should probably be included in the diff and will ALWAYS fail the diff.  `Untracked changes` isn't a term that Arcanist uses, so I'm not familiar with that one.  However, the question clearly states `untracked files`.

Comment: I'll leave my comment for reference, but something was messed up. I redid everything from scratch and it worked as expected. In addition to the error a above, arcanist also suggested that I make a `.gitignore` file and also some file (can't remember) in a `.git` directory

Comment: `arc diff --preview` makes for a really convenient multi-file diff-tool.  This is a great use-case.

Comment: I've been looking for the solution and have not found either. :( No idea why Arcanist can't ignore unstaged changes. And no, problem can't be solved with .gitignore. Sometimes you have to work with multiple features at the same time. And sometimes it's not git, but other source control system (mercurial in my case). hg shelve does not work on unstaged changes. In my opinion, it's a big thing that should be fixed in arcanist in future versions.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so to answer my own question, I just found out the answer to question 2. I can leave reviewers blank and create the review and edit the review from the web, which is a lot easier to do.

Answer (score 1):

Question is old but answer might still help others.
Use `arc diff [--update DXXXX] --allow-untracked`